# Game rating certificates for windows phone

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I made a simple game in silverlight for windows phone. When I try to publish it, marketplace asks me for game rating certificates. Where can I get this?

Since the game is very simple and free, it would be great if I can get this for free! :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It turns out that you can't submit games to Brazilian and South Korean markets without the game rating certificates.

Check http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/88477.aspx for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [advice is from the Win8 Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452763%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but the same applies for phone:

> To find out the rules for game ratings in your locale, or any locales
>   your game will be released in, and how to obtain a third-party rating
>   certificate, visit the rating board's website.

Comment: So, you have to basically contact the rating board to get the certificate, which might take quite a long time. At this moment only the Brazilian and Korean markets require a certificate. You can publish games to the other markets without any certificate.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 8 Store lists the following countries as requiring certificates: (South) Korea, New Zealand, South Africa, Brazil and Taiwan.